# Notify authors when a bounty is offered

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, bounty, notifications

Please automatically inform the authors of the question and any answers when someone posts a bounty.

---

I received an upvote on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30303676) to [How to wrap table cell at a maximum width in full width table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30303351).
When investigating (I only retained vague recollections about the question), I was amazed to see that it gathered 4 new answers (there was mine and one other before). So what happend, you may ask?

Nothing sinister, it's just that after the question was inactive for two months, someone stumbled across it and [sponsored a sizable bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30303351/revisions).

Wouldn't it be nice if anyone already having a stake in the question (having posted it or an answer) was automatically notified, so they can consider enhancing their post if possible and useful?

Comment: If they're looking for a different approach to the accepted answer, that raises a red flag; what did they change from their original question and accepted answer combo that is now warranting a ton more attention (and could invalidate existing answers)?

Comment: it was just an example, users sometimes don't want the JS solution only, but want a Pure CSS solution only or vice verse. and for that they are willing to offer a bounty, It might happen that there is no accepted answer yet

Comment: That still has a bit of a smell about it; it's like they're trying to change around *some* aspect of what they asked earlier.  I dunno; personally I'd cast a critical eye on anyone that used bounties in that way.

Comment: look at this example from the question mention. the user asks for a CSS solution only. until the bounty was 2 answers there (check dates may 18th). after the bounty set it raised to 6, all of them CSS solutions as user who offered the bounty asked. So nothing smells bad here. because even the user who's offering the bounty is giving an CSS answer, although too modern yet.
The idea here it is just notify users who already answered before the bounty been set

Comment: [I feel the same way](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333838/i-am-not-notified-on-bounties-on-my-questions) dippas, +1!

Comment: Any SO staff member are willing to see this Feature request?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, that is a great idea. In fact, I had the exact same thing happen to, and it was really annoying, because I wish I could have communicated with the bounty-setter. I mean, I already spent my time to answer the OP, and have knowledge of the issue at hand...so helping the bounty-setter solve their issue would be no problem...

...except I was not notified until the very end of the bounty when people normally look at bounties and upvote.

**So, yes, this is a great idea! Would love to see it implemented; in fact, I don't understand why this was not implemented already.**

Comment: [Similar experience here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333838/i-am-not-notified-on-bounties-on-my-questions)! +1!