# I am not notified on bounties on my questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, bounty, notifications

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38964007/active-tasks-is-a-negative-number-spark-ui) got a bounty, and I had no idea about it! Wouldn't it be nice to get a notification?

---

The motivation is that I want to help too, in getting the question answered. I had almost forgotten about the question, but now that I saw that others are also concerned, I will broadcast the question to other people. But I only saw the bounty from chance..BTW, if you find the question interesting, please upvote, so that more people can see it! :)

Comment: Ohhh come on search-when-posting the question!!! I was looking for that, but it didn't show up, probably from the syntax?! Thank you very much @BhargavRao for providing the link! I will accept the dupe, after reading a bit. :)